# Why should `std::align_val_t` restrict implicit conversion?

Tags: c++, interface, new-operator, software-design, memory-alignment

`std::align_val_t` restricts implicit conversion:

```
// won't compile
// std::align_val_t align = 64;

auto aln = std::align_val_t{64};
```

When I have alignment in my code, should I **retain** this **restriction of implicit conversion** in my interface?

Is it a good practice allowing `size_t` parameter be implicitly converted to `align_val_t`?

For example:

```
[[no_discard]] T* make_copy_on_heap(const T (array&) [N], std::align_val_t aln )
```

versus

```
[[no_discard]] T* make_copy_on_heap(const T (array&) [N], std::size_t aln )
```

If I can allow the later (`size_t` interface), why should `std::align_val_t` restrict implicit conversion in the first place?

Comment: cppreference.com says "placement forms of allocation and deallocation functions that take std::size_t as an additional parameter are already in use". So that's one reason why `align_val_t` is an `enum`. It disambiguates for overload resolution.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Ah I forgot about that. That must be one. Definitely.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf If my interface lacks of any `size_t`, the `align_val_t` is only numeric there. Can I remove its restriction by take in as `size_t` and convert into `align_val_t` in implementatoin?

Answer (score 1):

`align_val_t` is a strongly-typed enum, and those do not allow implicit conversion to/from integers.

`align_val_t` is a hack from the start--the type only exists to prevent confusion with regular other parameters.

Comment: If the order of paramters is the reason (like in `operator new`), when my interface doesn't contain any `size_t`, so I can allow `size_t` to implicitly converted into `align_val_t`?